# How can I update the state from parent component to child component when its passed as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have the parent component that sets the counter for score and I'm passing it to the child component. I have a function in the parent component called `resetBoard()` that I need to use to reset that counter back to 0. Currently this code does not update the state for score when the button is pressed. The full results displays the current still instead of resetting to 0.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Player from './Player';

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        players: 2,
        score: 0
    }

    resetBoard = () => {
        this.setState( { score: 0} )
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Player score={this.state.score} name={(this.state.players <= 2 ? "Team One" : "Player One")}/>

                <button onClick={this.resetBoard}>Reset Board</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

import React from 'react';


export default class Player extends React.Component {

    state = {
        score: this.props.score
    }

    updateScoreFive = () => {
        return this.setState({score: this.state.score + 5})
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.score >= 150) {
            console.log('winner')
        }
    }

    render(props) {
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
            <p>{this.state.score}</p>
            <button onClick={this.updateScoreFive}>5</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent component

```
resetBoard = () => {
 this.setState({counter: 0});
}
```

Pass this function to child component.

```
<ChildComponent onClick={this.resetBoard }/>
```

Now in Child component use it on button.

```
<button  onClick={props.onClick} />
```

or

```
<button  onClick={this.props.onClick} />
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe this and the other comment should get me where I need to be on this project and wrapped up!

Answer (score 0):

The score state should all be stored/updated in one place, instead of having both parent and child have their own state. If you store it all in `App`'s state, and move `updateScoreFive` into `App` as well, you can pass the score and a reference to the function down into `Player`, which can be converted to a stateless functional component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Player = (props) => {
  if (props.score >= 150) {
    console.log('winner');
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <p>{props.score}</p>
      <button onClick={props.updateScoreFive}>5</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And in `App`:

```
<Player updateScoreFive={this.updateScoreFive} ... />
```

This is a good article on how to think about where state should be stored: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: That makes sense. I will give that a try and let you know if that is the solution to my problem (which i think it is). New to React so I didn't that we could pass function too.